# Decompile JS into JSX

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I wrote an app in React a few months ago and it seems I didn't keep the source JSX code.  I have the Babel-compiled JS code.

Is there a way to decompile this back into JSX code?  Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this?: https://github.com/rogeriochaves/react-decompiler

Comment: Thanks but i already check that, it doesnt do what I decribe above

Answer (score 7):

If you have the .map files (outputted by default with most bundlers - including Create React App) you can use the [npm source-map package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map) to convert those files back to the source.

An example of an AWS Lambda function that makes use of this [can be found here](https://github.com/jonoirwinrsa/sourcemap-pirate/blob/master/handler.js)

Alternatively if your site is deployed somewhere checkout the Source tab of Chrome devtools - it does the same thing as the package and stitches compiled JS code and source-maps back together.

[image]